# Select Certain Column from Table1 and Insert to Certain Column in Table2 with Where Clause Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Table1**:

```
|Id|Category_Id|Type_Id|Code|
+--+-----------+-------+----+
|1 |1          |1      |A   |
|3 |2          |1      |B   |
|4 |1          |3      |C   |
```

**Table2**:

```
|Id|Category_Id|Type_Id|Code_Id|
+--+-----------+-------+-------+    
|1 |1          |1      |NULL   |
|3 |2          |1      |NULL   |
|5 |9          |7      |NULL   |
```

As you can see, the column 'Code_Id' in Table2 is NULL. I need to update that column with the values from column 'Id' in Table1 with condition where values in columns 'Category_Id' and 'Type_Id' in Table1 match values in columns 'Category_Id' and 'Type_Id' in Table2.

How am I supposed to do that? Thank you and looking forward to your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Join Update

```
update t2 set code_id=t1.id
from table2
join table1 t1 on t1.type_id=t2.type_id and t1.category_id=t2.category_id
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I'm trying to accept this answer but the site keeps telling me that I can accept an answer in 5 minutes. Anyway, thank you for your kind help. :)

Answer (score 2):

use join

```
UPDATE t2
SET Code_Id = t1.Id
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 on t2.Type_Id=t1.Type_Id and t2.Category_Id=t1.Category_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

It's must require alias in all condition like the set, where because might be same column name in multiple tables than an error comes.

```
UPDATE A 
set A.code_id = B.id
FROM table2 A
INNER JOIN table1 B on B.type_id=A.type_id and B.category_id=A.category_id
```